# integrated development environment (IDE) for Web Assembly?

Tags: c++, qt, webassembly

I've been doing a lot of research into the availability of IDE(-eske) solutions for working with Web Assembly. In that research, So far, I found very little info on active, cross platform, solutions for working with C++ and cross-compiling it to Web Assembly.

**Research so far**

So far, the most interesting development is in Qt:

https://blog.qt.io/blog/2018/05/22/qt-for-webassembly/

The people behind Qt are working on integrating their tools with the compiler tools of Emscripten, but the project is still in early development and it doesn't seem to be production ready.

Another alternative, Visual Studio from Microsoft which is sadly not cross platform, is limited to older versions:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28314162/building-emscripten-project-with-an-ide

Other then that there are not really any concrete solutions,and certainly not any that are out and stable.

I also found somebody who tried to link Netbeans to emscripten, 4 years ago, but the information seems outdates as I can't get it to work:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24834330/getting-netbeans-c-parser-to-work-with-emscripten

**My question**

Are there as of now, any available IDE solutions that work well when targetting Web Assembly?

I'm intentionally looking for an IDE solution because I'll have to share this project with other developers, and the change of the project going anywhere is certainly dependent on the easy of adopting.

Alternatively, if you have a custom way of connecting your IDE of choice to emscripten, could you share your setup and possible tips?